# Vue JSON Write & Read

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3

This question is kind of specific, but I've looked and can't find the answer here. I am working with Vue3 and trying to write a JSON and then read it. I'm not 100% sure how it works with this though. This is what I have in my js file:

```js
class Post {
        constructor(title, link, img, rank) {
          this.title = title;
          this.link = link;
          this.img = img;
          this.rank = rank;
        }
      }

      const app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          search: "",
          postList: [
            new Post(
              "Monke",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "Queen",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "Bly",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "Blqc",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "BlqckLight",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "BlqckKing",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"            
            ),

            new Post(
              "BlqckWTF",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "BlqckFTW",
              "test1.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            ),

            new Post(
              "BlqckQueen",
              "test.html",
              "head.png",
              "Admin"
            )
          ]
        },

        computed: {
          filteredList() {
            return this.postList.filter((post) => {
              return post.title
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
          }
        }
      });
      
    for (let i = 0; i < Post.length; i++) {
        console.log(Post.name[i])
    }
```

The `console.log` is trying to fetch all the names but it will return like this

```
P
o
s
t
```

I know I need to now get all the names and stats to make a JSON, but making it is challenging to me, I need to return it like this

```json
[
  {
    “name”: “Monke”,
    “link”: “test.html”,
    “img”: “head.png”,
    “rank”: “Admin”
  },
  {
    “name”: “Bly”,
    “link”: “test.html”,
    “img”: “head.png”,
    “rank”: “Admin”
  }
]
```

Etc. I'm sorry if this has been asked and answered before, but I simply couldn’t find it.

I then am wanting to read the JSON file which I had

```js
  JSON.parse(readFileSync(“players”).toString())
```

Sorry for the inconvenience if any, but I'm not very good with JSON.

Comment: You're calling `Post.length` and `Post.name` on the actual `Post` class, when perhaps you should be accessing it from somewhere else like `app.data.postList`.

Comment: Yes but how would I get the data to a var and or get all the Posts to an object for reading and writing to a json?

Comment: The function `JSON.stringify()` may be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over your class `Post`, but you should be iterating over your list of `Post`s. Then the log statement is outside of the Vue app, so you can't access the list. Then you are naming it `title` in the class but try to access a property called `name`.

I am not used to use the options API, but you could try the mounted hook within your app:

```
class Post {
    constructor(title, link, img, rank) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.img = img;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
}

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        search: '',
        postList: []
    },
    computed: {
        filteredList() {
            return this.postList.filter((post) => post.title
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.postList = JSON.parse(readFileSync('players').toString());
        this.postList.forEach((post) => console.log(post.title));
    }
});
```

Comment: No matter where I put this it always give me errors, Im not sure where you want me to put it besides in the class.

Comment: @Monke, I updated the answer to show the full (untested) code.